# How can I using state instead of setTimeout?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-hooks, settimeout, visualization

I am learning react and decided to try create a sorting visualizer. I started with bubble sort and pretty much succeeded creating a basic visualizer. `setTimeout` was the main function that I used to apply the visualization.

I felt that relaying on `setTimeout` does not utilize react enough and I wanted to try different approach, applying the visualization with `useState` hook and the rerendering that is happening when changing the state. I understand that `useState` hook is asynchronous, and will not immediately reflect.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 10;

const DEFAULT_COLOR = 'black';

const randomIntFromInterval = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const Dummy = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const [numberOfElements, setNumberOfElements] = useState(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);
    const [doneElements, setDoneElements] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        resetArray();
    }, []);

    const resetArray = () => {
        const arr1 = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = randomIntFromInterval(5, 100);
        }
        console.log(arr1);
        setArr(arr1);
    }

    const bubbleSort = (arr, n) => {
        let i, j, temp, swapped, delay = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
            swapped = false;
            for(j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) 
            {
                createColor(j, j + 1, delay++, 'darkred');
                if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) 
                {
                    // swap arr[j] and arr[j+1] 
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                    createAnimation(j, j + 1, delay++);
                }
                createColor(j, j + 1, delay++, 'black');
            }
            createSingleColor(n - i - 1, delay++, 'green');

            // If no two elements were  
            // swapped by inner loop, then break 
            if(swapped === false) break;
        }

        for(let k = 0; k < n - i - 1; k++) {
            createSingleColor(k, delay++, 'green');
        }
    }

    const createAnimation = (one, two, delay) => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        setTimeout(() => {
            const barOneHeight = arrayBars[one].style.height;
            const barTwoHeight = arrayBars[two].style.height;
            arrayBars[two].style.height = `${barOneHeight}`;
            arrayBars[one].style.height = `${barTwoHeight}`;
        }, 250 * delay);
    }

    const createColor = (one, two, delay, color) => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        setTimeout(() => {
            arrayBars[two].style.backgroundColor = color;
            arrayBars[one].style.backgroundColor = color;
        }, 250 * delay); 
    }

    const createSingleColor = (index, delay, color) => {
        const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
        setTimeout(() => {
            arrayBars[index].style.backgroundColor = color;
        }, 250 * delay); 
    }

    const handleSort = (arr) => {
        bubbleSort(arr, arr.length);
    }

    const handlerRange = (e) => {
        setNumberOfElements(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="array-container">
                {arr.map((value, idx) => (
                    <div className="array-bar"
                         key={idx}
                         style={{
                            backgroundColor: 'black',
                            height: `${value}px`,
                            width: `${100 / arr.length}%`,
                            display: 'inline-block',
                            margin: '0 1px'
                         }}>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

            <div className="buttons-container">
                <button onClick={() => handleSort(arr)}>Sort!</button>
                <button onClick={() => resetArray()}>Reset</button>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    setDoneElements([...doneElements, 7]);
                    console.log(doneElements);}}>print</button>
            </div>
            <div className="slider-container">
                1
                <input type="range" 
                       min="1" 
                       max="100" 
                       onChange={(e) => handlerRange(e)} 
                       className="slider" 
                       id="myRange" 
                />
                100
            </div>
            {numberOfElements}

        </div>
    );
}

export default Dummy;
```

For example when I tried using the `setDoneElements` in the `bubblesort` function I messed up the visualization.

Is there a way to use hooks to apply the visualization, and not to rely on `setTimeout` that much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const shortid = require('shortid');

const randomIntFromInterval = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const Dummy2 = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const [length, setLength] = useState(10);
    const [doneElements, setDoneElements] = useState([]);
    const [compareElements, setCompareElements] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        generateArray();
    }, [length]);

    const generateArray = () => {
        setDoneElements([]);
        setCompareElements([]);
        const tempArr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            tempArr.push(randomIntFromInterval(7, 107));
        }
        setArr([...tempArr]);
    }

    const handleLength = (e) => {
        setLength(e.target.value);
    }

    const bubbleSort = () => {
        let i, j, swapped, delay = 100;
        const tempArr = [...arr];
        const tempDoneElements = [...doneElements];
        for(i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) 
        {
            swapped = false;
            for(j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) 
            {
                createColor([j, j + 1], delay, 'COMPARE');
                delay += 100;
                if(tempArr[j] > tempArr[j + 1]) 
                {
                    createAnimation(tempArr, j, j + 1, delay);
                    delay += 100;
                    swapped = true;
                }
                createColor([], delay, 'NONE');
                delay += 100;
            }
            tempDoneElements.push(length - i - 1);
            createColor(tempDoneElements, delay, 'DONE');
            delay += 100;

            // If no two elements were  
            // swapped by inner loop, then break 
            if(swapped === false) break;
        }

        for(let k = 0; k < length - i - 1; k++) {
            tempDoneElements.push(k);
        }
        createColor(tempDoneElements, delay, 'DONE');
        delay += 100;
    }

    const createAnimation = (tempArr, indexOne, indexTwo, delay) => {
        const temp = tempArr[indexOne];
        tempArr[indexOne] = tempArr[indexTwo];
        tempArr[indexTwo] = temp;
        const newArr = [...tempArr];
        setTimeout(() => {
            setArr([...newArr]);
          }, delay);
    }

    const createColor = (tempElements, delay, action) => {
        switch(action) {
            case 'DONE': 
                const newDoneElements = [...tempElements];
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setDoneElements([...newDoneElements]);
                }, delay);
                break;
            case 'COMPARE':
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setCompareElements([...tempElements]);
                }, delay);
                break;
            default:
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setCompareElements([]);
                }, delay);
        }
    }

    const maxVal = Math.max(...arr);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="array-container" style={{height: '50%'}}>
                {arr.map((value, idx) => (
                    <div className="array-element"
                         key={shortid.generate()}
                         style={{height: `${(value * 100 / maxVal).toFixed()}%`,
                                 width: `calc(${100 / length}% - 2px)`,
                                 margin: '0 1px',
                                 display: 'inline-block',
                                 backgroundColor: compareElements.includes(idx) ? 'darkred' : 
                                                  doneElements.includes(idx) ? 'green' : 'black',
                                 color: 'white'}}
                    ></div>))
                }
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => generateArray()}>New array</button>
                <button onClick={() => bubbleSort()}>Sort</button>
            </div>
            <div className="slider-container">
                1
                <input type="range" 
                       min="1" 
                       max="100" 
                       onChange={(e) => handleLength(e)} 
                       className="slider" 
                       id="myRange" 
                />
                100
            </div>
            {length}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dummy2;
```

Instead of messing with the DOM I used state to keep track of changes so react will be charge of changing things.

When manipulating the array in the sorting function we need to remember that `arr` is part of state therefore it is immutable. any change that we do we need to do on a duplicate and apply the changes at the right time so an animation will occur, that is what I done in the `createAnimation` function.

To keep track on the colors I added to the state `doneElements` and `compareElements`. Every time an element get to it's final position it's index is added to `doneElements`. At any given time only two elements are compared therefore `compareElements` will contain only two elements or none.